# How to load controller in angular js using require js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, requirejs, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

I am trying to load a controller so that my view will display. Actually I write my controller `.Route` or `config` also .But I am not able to load my controller and route file how to load controller using `require.js` so that my `login.html` page is display?

Here is my Plunker:

> http://plnkr.co/edit/DlI7CikKCL1cW5XGepGF?p=preview

**main.js**

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        ionic:'http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.1/js/ionic.bundle.min',

    },
    shim: {
        ionic : {exports : 'ionic'}
    }
});
```

**route.js**

```
/*global define, require */

define(['app'], function (app) {
    'use strict';

    app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
            function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

            $stateProvider
                .state('login', {
                    url: "/login",
                    templateUrl: "login.html",
                    controller: 'LoginCtrl'
                })

            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/login");

        }]);


});
```

Any guess how to load view?

Comment: updated one http://plnkr.co/edit/F3YwSw1q83XBCFo1jpMD?p=preview

Comment: Make sure you add angular for requirejs

Comment: already added  require js

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do:

**main.js**

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        ionic:'http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.1/js/ionic.bundle.min',

    },
    shim: {
        ionic : {exports : 'ionic'}
    },callback: function () {
        'use strict';

        require([
            'angular',
            'route',
            'app'
        ], function (angular) {
            // init app
            angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
        });
    }
    });
```

**app.js**

```
define(['ionic',
    './LoginCtrl',],

    function (angular) {
        'use strict';

        var app = angular.module('app', [
            'ionic','app.controllers']);

        return app;

    });
```

**LoginCtrl.js**

```
/*global define, console */
define(['angular'], function (ng) {
    'use strict';

    return ng.module('app.controllers', ['$scope','$state'
    ,function ctrl($scope, $state) {

        $scope.login = function () {
          alert("Login is clicked")
        };

    }]);
});
```

You can follow the tips here - https://www.startersquad.com/blog/angularjs-requirejs/